# jQuery's .then() not executing onFailure function even though GET request encountered an error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convince [.then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) to execute it's failure condition.

I have the following. Note that taskID has been replaced with -1 to induce failure.

```
load: function (taskID) {
    $.when(
        $('#OrderDetails').load('../../csweb/Orders/OrderDetails'),
        $('#TaskDetails').load('../../csweb/Orders/TaskDetails/?taskID=' + -1),
        $('#DeviceDetails').load('../../csweb/Orders/DeviceDetails'),
        $('#Provisioning').load('../../csweb/Orders/Provisioning'),
        $('#Activity').load('../../csweb/Orders/Activity')
    ).then(onDisplayLoadSuccess, onDisplayLoadFailure);
}

var onDisplayLoadSuccess = function () {
    console.log("onDisplayLoadSuccess!");
};

var onDisplayLoadFailure = function () {
    console.log("onDisplayLoadFailure!");
};
```

[image]

From [documentation of .when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

> In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when, the method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been passed. The method will resolve its master Deferred as soon as all the Deferreds resolve, or **reject the master Deferred as soon as one of the Deferreds is rejected**.

Since one of my load requests fails -- shouldn't then be executing onDisplayLoadFailure?

Comment: Does the `$('sel').load()` return a Deferred?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I am using .load to load data into views. I'm realizing that I might be using .then() improperly and it might be returning immediately. Going to have to learn more about Deferred.

Comment: It needs to be a `jqXHR` object, which is a Deferred-qualified object (and implements Promise). [`$('sel').load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), according to the jQuery docs, returns a jQuery object, while [`$.get()` returns jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). I think the problem is you're using `$('sel').load()` and not a jQuery shorthand method that returns a jqXHR/Deferred object.

Comment: At least looking at it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gzkbp/ The two `$.get` calls which should call the `onDisplayLoadFailure` do call them, while the `$('#load')` calls always return `onDisplayLoadSuccess`.